# Filebeats filbeat.yml file location

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I've installed Filebeats in my machine, and I was wondering in which location should the configuration file "filebeat.yml" should stay, once I've found 2 diretories for Elastic

- C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Beats\filebeat
  -> [I can find also filebeat yml examples here][1]
- C:\Program Files\Elastic\Beats\8.1.2\filebeat

Can someone help ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xqgU.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to have a .yml file in a location that the filebeat program can access. Either one would work just fine. All you would do is point the running filebeat to the desired filebeat.yml file. For example, on Linux, if I create a new .yml file called example.yml, I would run it by doing ./filebeat -c /example.yml.
The same should be the case for Windows.